# Как разместить два блока на одной строке?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Подскажите, как правильно разместить два блока, которые обведены красной рамкой?
(без использования фреймворков)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте ваш код

Comment: Можно использовать абсолютное позиционирование

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Способов располагать блоки в строку несколько, вы можете пойти самым обычным путем (по-старинке), пример вам привел @IvanTokar. Также можно воспользоваться `flexbox` или `grid`, это если просто использовать только возможности самих HTML и CSS.

Пример, используя `grid`:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: '. grid-container-social . copyrights . . '; 
  align-content: center;
}
.copyrights {
  grid-area: copyrights;
}
.grid-container > div {
  background-color:lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.grid-container-social {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: grid-container-social;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto  auto auto auto;
  align-content: center;
}
.div-socnetw {
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 240, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding:5px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="grid-container-social">
    <div class="div-socnetw">1</div>
    <div class="div-socnetw">2</div>
    <div class="div-socnetw">3</div>  
    <div class="div-socnetw">4</div>
    <div class="div-socnetw">5</div>
    <div class="div-socnetw">6</div>  
  </div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="copyrights">2017. All Right Reserved</div>  
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
</div>
```

Более подробнее можно почитать [на MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Grid)
В игровой форме можно разобраться с сеткой на [Grid Garden](http://cssgridgarden.com/)

Пример, используя `flexbox`:

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background-color:lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.flex-container-social {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
.div-socnetw {
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 240, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding:5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="flex-container-social">
    <div class="div-socnetw">1</div>
    <div class="div-socnetw">2</div>
    <div class="div-socnetw">3</div>  
    <div class="div-socnetw">4</div>
    <div class="div-socnetw">5</div>
    <div class="div-socnetw">6</div>  
  </div>
  <div class="copyrights">2017. All Right Reserved</div>
</div>
```

Подробнее про `flexbox` [на MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Flexbox)
Проработать вопрос в игровой форме на сайте [Flexbox Froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/)

Я бы вам рекомендовал больше давить на `flexbox` он актуальный и поддерживается современными браузерами, и самое главное с ним очень просто работать, `grid` практически подтянулся. Все основные браузеры его уже поддерживают. Но с ним надо посидеть.

Comment: хороший, информативный ответ

Answer (score 2):

1. Вы можете использовать flexbox (здесь можно попрактиковаться [Flexbox Playground](https://demos.scotch.io/visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-flexbox-playground/demos))
2. Или же по старинке:

```css
.container {
 padding: 10px;
 background: #eee;
 text-align: center;
 clear: both;
}

.left {
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="left">left content</div>
 <div>center content</div>
</div>
```