# Как сверстать два столбца внутри <div>?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Как здесь поднять второй столбик?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.fon_plusov_producta {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.plusi_producta {
  padding-left: 464px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #445161;
}
.perviy_stolbik {
  padding-top: 31px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #333333;
}
.vtoroy_stolbik {
  padding-left: 640px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="fon_plusov_producta">
  <div class="plusi_producta">
    Dignity and pluses product
  </div>
  <div class="sami_plusi">
    <div class="perviy_stolbik">
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
    </div>
    <div class="vtoroy_stolbik">
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А каки где ее задать?

Comment: А как им пользоваться то? ТАкое ощущение, что я верстальщик-сеньор)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну если не знаете flex, то хоть float-то Вы должны знать:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fon_plusov_producta {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.plusi_producta {
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #445161;
  text-align: center;
}
.perviy_stolbik,
.vtoroy_stolbik {
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #333333;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fon_plusov_producta">
  <div class="plusi_producta">
    Dignity and pluses product
  </div>
  <div class="sami_plusi">
    <div class="perviy_stolbik">
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
    </div>
    <div class="vtoroy_stolbik">
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: float тоже не знаю) Я только начал изучать, но всё равно спасибо)

Comment: @KuliSH, вот есть хорошие курсы: https://htmlacademy.ru/, там первые несколько уроков бесплатные, но это самые основы - крайне рекомендую пройти, прежде чем что-то самостоятельно верстать

Comment: Спасибо за совет

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте

```
.vtoroy_stolbik {
  padding-top: 31px;
}
```

и уберите padding-left (настройте дальше как нужно)

Применяйте flexbox:

```css
.sami_plusi {
  display: flex;
}
```

Дальше можно сделать width: 50% столбцам

Comment: Уже пробовал, не помогло

Comment: Поправила ответ

Answer (score 3):

Чтоб понять как работает технология `flexbox`, необходимо почитать чуть информации и немного попрактиковаться. Про свойство `flex` можно почитать тут:

[Справочник CSS. flex](https://webref.ru/css/flex)

Далее, следующий способ ровнять блоки так как необходимо, это использование `grid css`.

Пример использования данной технологии как-то приводил (включая и `flex`):

[Как разместить два блока на одной строке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/934837/262779)

Далее про `grid` можно почитать тут:

[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Пример использования `flex` в этом коде:

```css
.fon_plusov_producta {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: Arial;
} /* для фона не нужно создавать отдельный блок */
.sami_plusi {
  display: flex;
   /* блоки особо не фиксил, тут суть показать, что flex необходимо применить к родителю */
}
.plusi_producta {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #445161;
}
.perviy_stolbik {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333333;
}
.vtoroy_stolbik {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;  
  color: #333333;
```

```html
<div class="fon_plusov_producta">
  <div class="plusi_producta">
    Dignity and pluses product
  </div>
  <div class="sami_plusi">
    <div class="perviy_stolbik">
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
    </div>
    <div class="vtoroy_stolbik">
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
      <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
      impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
      perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Используйте, те технологии которые вам понятны на данный момент, далее прокачивайтесь, добавляйте что-то новое. Понятен `float` делайте с ним и никого не слушайте. Далее изучите что-то более сложное к примеру тот же `grid` ну и вышеупомянутый `flex`. Всё надо делать постепенно, это нормально в процессе обучения. Позже поймёте как лучше и удобнее вам что-либо делать. Но знать придёться их все

Comment: Вам в ответах показали доступные варианты, изучите их внимательно, попробуйте. Пройдите по предложенным ссылкам от участников сообщества. Почитайте и вы разберетесь. Сложного если честно в этом вопросе ничего нет.

Comment: Также гляньте на Bootstrap позже, там много чего реализовано уже, ускорит вас существенно

Answer (score 3):

Для тех, кто в гробу видел эти ваши флексы, пихаемые где надо и не надо:

```css
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fon_plusov_producta {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sami_plusi{
    font-size:0;  /* ооочень грязный хак */
}
.plusi_producta {
    padding-top: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #445161;
    text-align: center;
}
.perviy_stolbik,
.vtoroy_stolbik {
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #333333;
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;  /* блочно-строчная модель */
    vertical-align:top;  /* и тянем наверх */
}
```

```html
<div class="fon_plusov_producta">
    <div class="plusi_producta">
        Dignity and pluses product
    </div>
    <div class="sami_plusi">
        <div class="perviy_stolbik">
            <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
          impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
          perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
            <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
          impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
          perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
            <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
          impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
          perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
        </div>
        <div class="vtoroy_stolbik">
            <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
          impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
          perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
            <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
          impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
          perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
            <li>Delectus dolorem vero quae beatae quasi dolor deserunt iste amet atque,<br>
          impedit iure placeat, ullam. Reprehenderit aliquam, nemo cum velit ratione<br>
          perferendis quas, maxime, quaerat porro totam, dolore minus inventore.</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Старайтесь не использовать `float`

Comment: Что за странный совет "Старайтесь не использовать float"? Вы это с чего взяли? Целый Бутстрап 3 построен на float

Comment: `float` ещё не умер. Но при всех раскладах вся вёрстка перекочует на `grid` и `flex`, рано или поздно

Comment: Ну, нужный результат для ТС тут есть, так что +1

Comment: «ооочень грязный хак» — это и есть основная причина, почему **нужно** использовать float ;)

Comment: @andreymal да ладно, проблему решает - решает. А для ТС важно видеть вопрос под разными углами, это хорошо. Аргумент автор конечно выложил "железобетонный", но это такое уже...

Comment: float, как известно "схлопывает" элементы, и без родительского `overflow:hidden` для неопытных новичков, порой, вызывает жжение в известном месте

Comment: @DaemonHK собственно, нужно всего лишь изучить `overflow:hidden` и `clear:both`, ничего сложного :)

Comment: @andreymal ну такое тоже, всюду совать их))

Comment: @DaemonHK всяко лучше чем `font-size:0` :D

Comment: @andreymal единственные у кого могут возникнуть вопросы это поисковики, но я пока однозначного ответа не нашел

Answer (score 0):

```
.sami_plusi div {
       vertical-align: top;
}
```